# Determinant of elementary permutation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, determinant, permutation-matrices

Why is the determinant of an *elementary* permutation matrix equal to $-1$?

I am brand new to determinants and I've tried expanding it and using cofactor expansion, but it's messy and complicated. I would prefer if someone could show me using expansion, but alternative methods are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every permutation matrix has determinant $-1$, but the elementary matrices which are permutation matrices (corresponding to interchanges of two rows) have determinant $-1$.  The easy way to see this is that (1) the identity matrix has determinant $1$, and (2) interchanging two rows or columns of a matrix multiplies its determinant by $-1$.

Comment: Ok, I guess what I'm asking is why does interchanging two rows or columns of a matrix multiply its determinant by -1?

Comment: @AbhishekMallela The determinant is defined to be an *alternate* multilinear map and alternate means changing the sign if we interchage two vector (i.e. coulumns) and we prove that $\det A=\det A^T$ so we have the same proprety for the rows.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. I would like to see by cofactor expansion.

Comment: For the $2 \times 2$ case it's obvious.  For $n > 2$, expand along a row that is not being interchanged,  note that the interchange switches two rows of each cofactor, and use mathematical induction.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if we interchange two rows (or two coulumns) of a matrix $A$ then its determinant change the sign.

The permutation matrix is obtained from the identity   matrix  (with determinant $1$) by interchanging their rows so its determinant is $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The elementary permutation matrix that swaps rows $i$ and $j$ is

$$\mathrm E_{ij} := \mathrm I - \mathrm{e}_i \mathrm{e}_i^\top - \mathrm{e}_j \mathrm{e}_j^\top + \mathrm{e}_i \mathrm{e}_j^\top + \mathrm{e}_j \mathrm{e}_i^\top = \mathrm I - \left( \mathrm{e}_i - \mathrm{e}_j \right) \left( \mathrm{e}_i - \mathrm{e}_j \right)^\top$$

Using the [Weinstein-Aronszajn determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity),

$$\det \left( \mathrm E_{ij} \right) = \det \left( \mathrm I - \left( \mathrm{e}_i - \mathrm{e}_j \right) \left( \mathrm{e}_i - \mathrm{e}_j \right)^\top \right) = 1 - \left( \mathrm{e}_i - \mathrm{e}_j \right)^\top \left( \mathrm{e}_i - \mathrm{e}_j \right) = 1 - \underbrace{\| \mathrm{e}_i - \mathrm{e}_j \|_2^2}_{=2} = \color{blue}{-1}$$