# Changing sign when interchanging rows of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, determinant

I am confused about one property of determinants which is: interchanging two rows or columns of a determinant changes the sign of the determinant. Does it mean that when I interchange rows of a determinant several times the sign keeps changing or it changes just once?

---

**Example**

$$\det A  =
\begin{vmatrix}
2 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
3 & 3 & 0 & 2\\
1 & 2 & -1 & 1\\
2 & 5 & 1 & 2
\end{vmatrix} = -
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 & 1\\
3 & 3 & 0 & 2\\
2 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
2 & 5 & 1 & 2
\end{vmatrix}
= -
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 & 1\\
0 & -3 & 3 & -1\\
0 & -5 & 3 & -3\\
0 & 1 & 3 & 0
\end{vmatrix}$$

where, firstly, the 1st and 3rd row were swapped, changing sign of determinant, and then the 2nd and 4th rows were swapped (changing the sign of determinant or not?).

Comment: keep changing. determinant multiply by $-1$ for each switching of 2 rows (or columns).

Comment: It would have to change each time. Imagine the other scenario. How could you decide whether someone had switched a pair of rows before they gave you the matrix in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Row swap changing sign of determinant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721504/row-swap-changing-sign-of-determinant)

Answer (score 1):

The sign changes every time you switch rows.