# Can you calculate the determinant along any row or column?

Tags: determinant

We are always taught to calculate a determinant using the top row of the matrix to guide the calculations. I have heard this is not a requirement and you can select any row/column. Could you please confirm my understanding that you can calculate the determinant not just by going along the 1st row, but you can via any row or column?

So in this case:

```
    |5, 0, 12|
A = |17,4, 9 |
    |23,0, 6 |
```

I could calculate:
$$(0)\det\binom{17, 9}{23, 6} - (4)\det\binom{5,12}{23, 6} + (0)\det\binom{5,12}{17,9}
= (4)((5)(6)-(12)(23))$$

So that way you can choose the simplest row or column (the one with the most zeros).

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct up to a sign.

Comment: Why don't they teach you that in high school?!  :-D
Thanks!

Comment: It’s not quite correct, you have to change the sign according to which row or column you are using. Try to compute the determnant of a 3x3 identity matrix and you will see it yourself

Comment: @Byron This works because of the row operations used in Gaussian elimination. Here are some tricks you can use: when you divide a row/column by a constant $c$, the determinant increases by a factor $c$, when you add two rows, the determinant stays the same, and when you swap two rows, the [sign changes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721504/row-swap-changing-sign-of-determinant). These tricks are commonly used in linear algebra to calculate the determinant more efficiently.

Comment: See the formula to compute the determinant under “Laplace expansion“: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant You can choose any row $i$, but the signs you have to put in front of the addends in the sum depend on $i$ itself. In practice, that means that you do the same thing as for the first row for all the odd rows, while for the even ones you change all the signs

Comment: I totally forgot that the process only works using the checkerboard pattern of + and - signs to create the cofactor matrix.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili - I see what you mean. Does that mean that if I choose an even row or column the order becomes -det()+det()-det()?

Comment: Yep, I just edited my previous comment

Comment: @LorenzoPompili - thanks. I get it now. thanks you